# Run a cron job on the odd day of the month on Tuesday?

Tags: linux, cron

I'm new in bash scripting. I need to run the job every Tuesday if the day of the month is odd.
I need something like this to check conditions:
[$(date '+%d') is odd ] && ...job...

But I cannot find how to check if the day is odd (

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if expr $(date +%d) % 2 > /dev/null; then
    echo the day is odd
else
    echo the day is even
fi
```

Or, if you want to be slightly less old-fashioned:

```
if (( $(date +%d) % 2 )); then echo odd; else echo even; fi
```

Comment: So, how can I implement it inline in the crontab as in this example ??: 30 8 * * 1 [`date +\%d` -le 07] && <job>  Will operator % work? I try to enter it in the termianl and got error

Comment: You can't do that sort of thing directly in the cron tab.  Run the script every day.  The first thing the script does is check if it is an odd Tuesday.  If not, quit.